# How would I make an array of all the integers between 0 and 1000?

Tags: c

Not finding this anywhere online google... And I'm not typing out the numbers one by one either because there has to be an easier way!

```
int myFunction(void) { 
        //numbers = ??????;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers); i++) {
                int currentNumber = numbers[i];
                if (currentNumber % 3 == 0 || currentNumber % 5 == 0) {
                        sum = sum + currentNumber;      
                }       
        }       
        printf("%d", sum);
}
```

UPDATE

Someone in the comments made a good point about just setting the condition of the for loop, however i'm still curious how one would make an array of integers [0,1,2,3,4..1000]

Comment: Create a for loop adding the numbers in the array? 
Also why not use the int i straight away: for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)

Comment: I don't understant what you want exactly.

Comment: nice one i should've thought of that. but just curious is there a way to do what i asked in the question?

Comment: `i < sizeof(numbers)` should be `i < sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(*numbers)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes any sense to actually create the array from 1-1000, if all you are going to do is `numbers[i]`, given that `numbers[i] == i`.  Using just a single integer `i`, you can save yourself from wasting the extra space.  If there is motivation other than what you have posted, you can do the following:

```c
int numbers[1001];
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
    numbers[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: @Matt, the OP wants the array values from 1 onwards. So I suggest you should change the for loop condition to begin from i=1.

Comment: @abhishek_naik: Given that the title of the question is: "How would I make an array of all the integers between 0 and 1000?" I'm not sure I agree.  Also, given that the OP posted the following comment: "nice i like this! thanks for the answer" it's probably fine the way it is.

Comment: @Matt, I agree. As you rightly pointed out, the title says '0 to 1000'. However at the same time, the last line in the question says, '1 to 1000'. The question is dubious. However since the OP has commented positively, better to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 8):

> How would I make an array of all the integers between 0 and 1000

Could take the direct, *and useless*, approach:

```
int main(void) {
  int a[1001] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
          18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
          35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,
          52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68,
          69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85,
          86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102,
          103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116,
          117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130,
          131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144,
          145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158,
          159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172,
          173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186,
          187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200,
          201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214,
          215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228,
          229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242,
          243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256,
          257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270,
          271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284,
          285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298,
          299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312,
          313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326,
          327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340,
          341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354,
          355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368,
          369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382,
          383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396,
          397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410,
          411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424,
          425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438,
          439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452,
          453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466,
          467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480,
          481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494,
          495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508,
          509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522,
          523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536,
          537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550,
          551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564,
          565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578,
          579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592,
          593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606,
          607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620,
          621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634,
          635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648,
          649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662,
          663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676,
          677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690,
          691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704,
          705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718,
          719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732,
          733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746,
          747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760,
          761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774,
          775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788,
          789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802,
          803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816,
          817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830,
          831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844,
          845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858,
          859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872,
          873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886,
          887, 888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900,
          901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914,
          915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928,
          929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942,
          943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956,
          957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970,
          971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984,
          985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998,
          999, 1000 };
  return a[0];
}
```

or something more interesting ...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
  size_t max = 1000;
  int *a = malloc((max+1) * sizeof *a);
  if (a) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
      a[i] = i;
    }
    free(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The **C** programming language has no a support, by default, for generate array as it has the Python, Ruby, JavaScript and may be other programming languages.

**In the Python**:

```
>>> tuple(range(1, 10, 1))
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

**In the Ruby**:

```
irb(main):004:0> Array (1..10)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**In the JavaScript**

```
> Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(function(currentValue, index) { return index;});
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

So, you need write something similar you own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h> // http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html


/*
    Prints an array of integer
 */
static void
printIntArray(int array[], size_t length) {
    char ending_charapter[] = ", ";
    putchar('[');
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
        if (i < length - 1) {
            printf("%s", ending_charapter);
        }
    }
    puts("]");
}


/*
    Fills an array of values in a passed range and with step.
    The step may be more or less 0.
    Return a non-zero value, if something went wrong.

    SIZE OF AN ARRAY IS A RESPONSIBILITY OF A PROGRAMMER.
 */
static int
rangeIntArray(int array[], const int start, const int end, const int step) {

    int value;
    int index = 0;

    // the step must not be zero
    if (step == 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        perror("Step must be not zero");
        return -1;
    }

    if (step > 0) {
        for (value = start; value < end; value += step, ++index) {
            array[index] = value;

        }
    } else if (step < 0) {
        for (value = start; value > end; value += step, ++index) {
            array[index] = value;

        }
    }
    return 0;

}


int
main (const int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    int arr1[10];
    rangeIntArray(arr1, 0, 10, 1);
    printIntArray(arr1, 10);

    int arr2[10];
    rangeIntArray(arr2, 0, -10, -1);
    printIntArray(arr2, 10);

    int arr3[4];
    rangeIntArray(arr3, 20, 10, -3);
    printIntArray(arr3, 4);

    int arr4[5];
    rangeIntArray(arr4, -20, -10, 2);
    printIntArray(arr4, 5);

    int arr5[5];
    rangeIntArray(arr5, -20, -10, -5);
    printIntArray(arr5, 5);

    int arr6[5];
    rangeIntArray(arr6, 20, 10, 5);
    printIntArray(arr6, 5);

    int arr7[5];
    int result = rangeIntArray(arr7, 20, 10, 0);
    if (result != 0) {
        puts("Raised error");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Results

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr1[10];
rangeIntArray(arr1, 0, 10, 1);
printIntArray(arr1, 10);
```

**Result**

*Generated an array with values from 0 to 10 (exclusive) by step +1*

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr2[10];
rangeIntArray(arr2, 0, -10, -1);
printIntArray(arr2, 10);
```

**Result**

*Generated an array with values from 0 to -10 (exclusive) by step -1*

```
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9]
```

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr3[4];
rangeIntArray(arr3, 20, 10, -3);
printIntArray(arr3, 4);
```

**Result**

*Generated an array with values from 20 to 10 (exclusive) by step -3*

```
[20, 17, 14, 11]
```

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr4[5];
rangeIntArray(arr4, -20, -10, 2);
printIntArray(arr4, 5);
```

**Result**

*Generated an array with values from -20 to -10 (exclusive) by step +2*

```
[-20, -18, -16, -14, -12]
```

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr5[5];
rangeIntArray(arr5, -20, -10, -5);
printIntArray(arr5, 5);
```

**Result**

*An upon attempt generated an array with values from -20 to -10 (exclusive) by step -5 changed no the array, so you will be see incorrect values*

```
[837314392, 32724, 837312896, 32724, 0]
```

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr6[5];
rangeIntArray(arr6, 20, 10, 5);
printIntArray(arr6, 5);
```

**Result**

*An upon attempt generated an array with values from 20 to 10 (exclusive) by step 5 changed no the array, so you will be see incorrect values*

```
[1, 32765, 837312936, 32724, 0]
```

---

**Part the code**

```
int arr7[5];
int result = rangeIntArray(arr7, 20, 10, 0);
if (result != 0) {
    puts("Raised error");
}
```

**Result**

*A value of the step must not be zero, so you will be see error*

```
Raised error
Step must be not zero: Invalid argument
```

---

**Notes:**

1. This code must be work for the C++ also, since the C++ is the C with classes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).
2. Tested only with the GCC

---

**Testing environment**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
$ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ nodejs --version
v6.9.2
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code, you don't need an extra array that has integers from `0` to `1000`. Use `i` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int currentNumber = i;
```

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` will not work for that case. take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)

just loop and add `i` to the array in each iteration:

```
int myFunction(void) { 
        int numbers[1001];
        for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
                numbers[i] = i;
        }       
}
```

Comment: As long as `numbers` is a (fixed size) array and not a pointer (where 'pointer' includes an array passed as an argument), `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0])` will give the number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted to do?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         array[i] = i+1;
         printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the array, a loop is the most intuitive:

```
int numbers[1001];
for(int i=0; i<1001;i++) {
    numbers[i] = i;
}
```

However it's usually a waste of space to use an array to store numbers when you can get them computationally. For example, you want to sum numbers in some range, right? You can use this method which uses considerably less space:

```
int x = 1000;
int sum = (x * (x + 1))/2;
```

Comment: `sum = (x * (x + 1))/2` : you forgot condition. `if (currentNumber % 3 == 0 || currentNumber % 5 == 0) {
                        sum = sum + currentNumber;`

Comment: I did forget! Sorry. In that case, it would be totally wrong to use that equation, although there may be still be a less-obvious computational answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated question
How one would make an array of integers [1,2,3,4,..,1000].

In the for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<=1000; i++) {}
```

The program will iterate the value in variable 'i' start from '0' (i = 0) until 'i' is less than or equal with 1000 (i <= 1000)
On each iteration, you can see from the third param in the for loop (i++) The program will add '1' to the value of 'i'. 
It is the same with (i = i + 1)
So, by thought it will run like this

```
i=0, i=1, i=2, i=3, i=4, . . ., i=1000(end-of-loop)
```

I'm taking the code below from one people who answered this question

```
int numbers[1001];
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
  numbers[i] = i;
```

After explaining how for loop works, now you can see the declaration of the array of integer as a variable where we store the data.

int numbers[1001] means that we declare an array variable sized of 1001 integer value, start from index 0 to index 1000

By illustration, it will be like:

```
numbers[0] - numbers[1] - numbers[2] - numbers[3] - numbers[4] - . . . - numbers[1000]
```

The number inside the "[]" tag is the index number of array variable and inside the for loop, you can see each index from array variable(numbers) is assigned by the value of variable 'i'.

```
numbers[0] = i = 0
i++
numbers[1] = i = 1
i++
numbers[2] = i = 2
i++
.
.
.
numbers[1000] = i = 1000
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to do this
`var myArray = [...Array(101).keys()]`

Answer (score -2):

To initialize an array in C, you use: `type arrayName [ size ]`.
A complete example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //initialize array
    int myArray [1000];

    int i;
    //for loop to add integers to array
    for(i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = i;
        printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A good tutorial on this is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm

Comment: Cause the array out of bounds.

Comment: You sure? Compiling and running that exact code with GCC 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 works perfectly. What compiler are you using?

Comment: you are kidding! `int myArray [999];` this can use  `myArray[0]`..`myarray[998]`, {i  | 0<= i <= 1000 } myArray[i] => you use `myArray[0]`..`myArray[1000]`.

Comment: well... Do you understand `1001 > 999` ?

Comment: What code I use is irrelevant. The code compiles and works, and does exactly what OP wanted in a simple and easy to understand way.

Comment: ┐('～`;)┌ We are apt to forget that the people who can not count the number exists in the world.

Comment: OHH, I see what you mean now. My apologies for misunderstanding. Answer has been edited to be correct.

Comment: Sigh...
You're also mis-counted.

Comment: I apologize, but I'm not understanding what I've done wrong

Comment: The `for()` first set `myArray[0] = 0;`, then `myArray[1] = 1;`,  ... `myArray[999] = 999;`, `myArray[1000] = 1000;`.  Hmmm, Would you say that is 1000 times `myArray[]` is set or 1001 times?  And the array has room for 1000 or 1001 elements?

Comment: The array has 1001 elements, as there are 1001 integers we need to set, from 0 to 1000

EDIT: OHH, I getcha now. I don't have a very good understanding of arrays, I don't use them much. Thanks for helping me out, though!

Answer (score -2):

you can either use tuples if u are in python or you can make a function that returns an array up to that number. For the second one you can use a recursion function :

```
ar=[]
def diff(n):
    if n==0:
        ar.append(0)
        return 
    else:
        ar.append(n)
        return diff(n-1)
```

where n is the number upto which you want the array, in your case 1000
.But using tuples in python will be much easy.

Comment: Why do you answer a C question with Python?